# how to align cells in a tabularx pagewidth table within two column document

Tags: tables, tabularx, minipage, two-column

Im writting a stats report for my dissertation an im struggling to create a table. the table needs to be page wide, ie, spanning both columns of my document and the cells need to be aligned. here is the code im working with currently:

```
\documentclass[scientificpaper,11pt, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{footmisc}


\maketitle
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[b]\setlength{\hfuzz}{1.1\columnwidth}
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \ttfamily ... 
        \begin{table}
            \caption{Model Specification}
            \label{tab:table2}
           \raggedright
Fixed Effect and Random Effect Models

    \medskip
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
    \small
    \makegapedcells
\begin{tablularx}{\pagewidth}
    \toprule
 \thead{Coefficient}  &  \thead{Estimate}   & \thead{STD}  & \thead{t-value}  & \thead{$P(>|t|)$}\\
\midrule 
Intercept & -2.6380 & 28.8535 & -0.0914 & 0.9279 \\
Independent &  31.9893 & 24.0831 &  1.3283 & 0.1956  \\
Female & -44.2676 & 108.4990 & -0.4080 & 0.6866 \\
Financial Expertise & -29.9851  & 39.7247 & -0.7548 & 0.4571 \\
CRO  & 6.3840 & 7.3231  & 0.8718 & 0.3913  \\
         

    \bottomrule

\smallskip
    \end{tablularx} ...
    \end{table}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}


\end document
```

Currently, the table loads at the top of the page, spanning both columns, however, all of the data in the cells is cramped on the left hand side whilst the headers are evenly spaced at the top.[image]

if anyone can offer any help it would be very much appreciated

Comment: Your document has no title, and you tabularx has no preamble, so the code is not compilable

Answer (score 2):

You have a bunch of problems/errors with your document example. I doubt that you with it produce showed image:

- You insert float `table` in float `figure`. Newer do this. Floats had not be ever inserted in any other environments.
- In preamble  you load some package twice and with different option.
- You not defined `tabularx` column specifications.
- It is unclear, what how to be align text between caption and `tabularx`
- you not define `title`
- `\makettitle` had to be after `begin{document}˙
- Where is defined option `scientificpaper`?

I guess, that you like to obtain the following table:

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

For it I use new table environment `tabullarray`, which unfortunately probably not installed in Overleaf yet. So you need to add it to your project yourself (ask its support for this):

```
\documentclass[11pt, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}
%\usepackage{wasysym}
%\usepackage{upquote}
%\usepackage{balance}
%\usepackage{footmisc}
%\raggedbottom
%
%\usepackage{rotating}
%\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
%\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
%\renewcommand\theadgape{}
%\setcellgapes{2pt}
%\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
%\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}

\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}


\begin{document}
%\maketitle
    \begin{table*}
\caption{Model Specification}
\label{tab:table2}
    \centering
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={l S[table-format=-2.4]    S[table-format= 3.4]
                            S[table-format=-1.4]    S[table-format= 1.4]
                         },
                 row{2}={font=\bfseries},
                 hspan=minimal  
                }
\SetCell[c=5]{l} Fixed Effect and Random Effect Models      \\
    \toprule
Coefficient & {{{Estimate}}}
                        & {{{STD}}} & {{{t-value}}} 
                                                & {{{$P(>|t|)$}}}   \\
    \midrule
Intercept   & -2.6380   & 28.8535   & -0.0914   & 0.9279    \\
Independent &  31.9893  & 24.0831   &  1.3283   & 0.1956    \\
Female      & -44.2676  & 108.4990  & -0.4080   & 0.6866    \\
Financial Expertise 
            & -29.9851  & 39.7247   & -0.7548   & 0.4571    \\
CRO         & 6.3840    & 7.3231    & 0.8718    & 0.3913    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table*}

\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
You can also use standard `tabular` table environment:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}
%\usepackage{wasysym}
%\usepackage{upquote}
%\usepackage{balance}
%\usepackage{footmisc}
%\raggedbottom
%
%\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
%\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}

\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
%\usepackage{tabularray}
%\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\begin{document}
%\maketitle
    \begin{table*}
\caption{Model Specification}
\label{tab:table2}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{l S[table-format=-2.4]    S[table-format= 3.4]
                      S[table-format=-1.4]    S[table-format= 1.4]
                   }  
\multicolumn{5}{l}{Fixed Effect and Random Effect Models}\\
    \toprule
\makecell{Coefficient}
            & {\thead{Estimate}}
                        & {\thead{STD}}
                                    & {\thead{t-value}} 
                                                & {\thead{$P(>|t|)$}}   \\
    \midrule
Intercept   & -2.6380   & 28.8535   & -0.0914   & 0.9279    \\
Independent &  31.9893  & 24.0831   &  1.3283   & 0.1956    \\
Female      & -44.2676  & 108.4990  & -0.4080   & 0.6866    \\
Financial Expertise 
            & -29.9851  & 39.7247   & -0.7548   & 0.4571    \\
CRO         & 6.3840    & 7.3231    & 0.8718    & 0.3913    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

which gives similar (the same) result as is obtained by the first example:

[image]